# Connecting signal to slot between classes in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsitem, qt-signals

Aim is to connect a signal of the top class `TicTacToe` with the QMainWindow class.

It throws an error: `TicTacToe cannot be converted to PyQt5.QtCore.QObject in this context`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from PyQt5.QtCore import (QLineF, QPointF, QRectF, pyqtSignal)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QIcon, QBrush, QColor, QPainter, QPixmap)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QAction, QMainWindow, QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem,
                             QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout,
                             QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton)

class TicTacToe(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TicTacToe, self).__init__()

    def paintEvent(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.drawLine(0,100,300,100)


    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0,0,300,300)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pos = event.pos()
        self.select(int(pos.x()/100), int(pos.y()/100))
        self.update()
        super(TicTacToe, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    messageSignal = pyqtSignal(int)


class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGraphicsView, self).__init__()
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.tic_tac_toe = TicTacToe()
        scene.addItem(self.tic_tac_toe)

        scene.addPixmap(QPixmap("exit.png"))

        self.setScene(scene)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        if key == Qt.Key_R:
            self.tic_tac_toe.reset()
        super(MyGraphicsView, self).keyPressEvent(event)

class Example(QMainWindow):    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.y = MyGraphicsView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.y)

        self.y.tic_tac_toe.messageSignal.connect (self.messageSlot)

        self.initUI()

    def messageSlot(self, val):
        self.statusBar().showMessage(val)


    def initUI(self):               
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Tools')


        self.setGeometry(30, 30, 30, 20)
        self.setWindowTitle('Menubar')    
        self.show()        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = Example()

    mainWindow.showFullScreen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only classes that inherit from `QObject` have the ability to create signals, for example `QWidget`, `QMainWIndow`, `QGraphicsView` inherit from `QObject` so they can have signals. But `QGraphicsItem` does not inherit from `QObject` because of efficiency issues so they do not have the ability to create signals. If you want an item that is a `QObject` you must use `QGraphicsObject`. In addition, the items have the `paint()` method, not `paintEvent()`.

```
class TicTacToe(QGraphicsObject):
    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.drawLine(0,100,300,100)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0,0,300,300)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pos = event.pos()
        # self.select(int(pos.x()/100), int(pos.y()/100))
        self.update()
        super(TicTacToe, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    messageSignal = pyqtSignal(int)
```

---

If you still want to use `QGraphicsItem`, a possible work around is to create a class that is in charge of the communication and that inherits from `QObject`:

```
class Helper(QObject):
    messageSignal = pyqtSignal(int)

class TicTacToe(QGraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, helper):
        super(TicTacToe, self).__init__()
        self.helper = helper

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.drawLine(0,100,300,100)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0,0,300,300)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pos = event.pos()
        self.helper.emit(10)
        # self.select(int(pos.x()/100), int(pos.y()/100))
        self.update()
        super(TicTacToe, self).mousePressEvent(event)


class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGraphicsView, self).__init__()
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.helper = Helper(self)
        self.tic_tac_toe = TicTacToe(self.helper)
        scene.addItem(self.tic_tac_toe)
        scene.addPixmap(QPixmap("exit.png"))
        self.setScene(scene)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        if key == Qt.Key_R:
            self.tic_tac_toe.reset()
        super(MyGraphicsView, self).keyPressEvent(event)

class Example(QMainWindow):    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.y = MyGraphicsView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.y)
        self.helper.messageSignal.connect(self.messageSlot)
        self.initUI()

    def messageSlot(self, val):
        self.statusBar().showMessage(val)


    def initUI(self):               
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Tools')
        self.setGeometry(30, 30, 30, 20)
        self.setWindowTitle('Menubar')    
        self.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your class `TicTacToe` doesn't inherit -- directly or otherwise -- from `QObject` meaning it can't be used by `Qt` as a signal source.

Try inheriting from [`QGraphicsObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsobject.html) instead...

```
class TicTacToe(QGraphicsObject):
def __init__(self):
    super(TicTacToe, self).__init__()
```

Comment: But I require QGraphicsItem. Does QGraphicsItem not inherit from QObject? Any work around?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I require QGraphicsItem"?  [`QGraphicsItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html) doesn't inherit from `QObject` but `QGraphicsObject` inherits from both `QGraphicsItem` *and* `QObject`.  So, as far as I can see replacing `QGraphicsItem` with `QGraphicsObject` should work just fine in this case.