# How to resize polygon by dragging its corners?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qgraphicsitem

I save points upon clicking mouse on a QGraphicsScene, append it on a list, and create a QGraphicsPolygonItem by looping through the list.

I use a custom QGraphicsScene which emits position whenever there is a mouse press event. The code is as below. (Credits for [SignalHelper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49815149/connecting-signal-to-slot-between-classes-in-pyqt))

```
class SignalHelper(QObject):
    messageSignal = QtCore.Signal(object)

class Scene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Scene, self).__init__(parent)
        self.helper = SignalHelper()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.helper.messageSignal.emit(event.scenePos())
```

Here is the code for my main window.

```
class main_window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
        self.pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0,0,0))                     
        self.pen.setWidth(5)                                             

        self.view = QGraphicsView(self)
        self.scene = Scene()
        self.btn_record_points = QPushButton("Record")
        self.btn_finished = QPushButton("Finished")
        
        self.view.setSceneRect(0, 0, 500,500)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.view)
        vbox.addWidget(self.btn_record_points)
        vbox.addWidget(self.btn_finished)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.point_list = []
        self.record_points = False

        #Signals
        self.btn_record_points.clicked.connect(self.enable_record_points)
        self.btn_finished.clicked.connect(self.create_polygon)
        self.scene.helper.messageSignal.connect(self.draw_points)
        
    def create_polygon(self):
        # Remove ellipses
        drawn_points = self.scene.items()
        for i in drawn_points:
            self.scene.removeItem(i)

        polygon = QGraphicsPolygonItem(QtGui.QPolygonF(self.point_list))
        polygon.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.scene.addItem(polygon)
        self.record_points = False
        self.point_list.clear()

    QtCore.Slot(QtCore.QPointF)
    def draw_points(self, point):
        if self.record_points == True:
            self.point_list.append(point)
            self.scene.addEllipse(point.toTuple()[0], point.toTuple()[1], 1, 1) 

    QtCore.Slot(bool)
    def enable_record_points(self):
        self.record_points = True
```

Here is an example of a random Polygon:

[image: GUI]

Note on how to use:

1. Press "Record" button
2. Click a number of times on the Scene
3. Press "Finsihed" button

Now that the Polygon is created, is there a way to resize the Polygon by dragging its corners?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By *"resize the Polygon dragging its corners"* I'm imagining you want to move the polygon's points around.

So here is one approach.

So, first make your polygon selectable, once the polygon is selected iterate through the polygon's points and draw an ellipse at each point. Store the ellipse, polygon_point_index mapping.

Now check which ellipse is selected by iterating through the mapping_list, then use this ellipse, polygon_index mapping to update the specific point of the polygon.

here is an example (which you may improve):

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class Scene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Scene, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.record_points = True
        self.selected = None  # the selected polygon
        self.points_lst = []  # points that are stored when recording
        self.corner_points = []  # This contains corner point and control point mapping
        self.selected_corner = None
        self.poly_points = [] # points that are stored when resizing (You could instead reuse points_lst)

    def record(self):
        self.record_points = True

    def removeControlPoints(self):
        """ removes the control points (i,e the ellipse)"""
        for ellipse, _ in self.corner_points:
            self.removeItem(ellipse)

        self.corner_points = []

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(Scene, self).mousePressEvent(event)

        if self.record_points:
            self.points_lst.append(event.scenePos())
            return

        for point in self.corner_points:
            if point[0].contains(event.scenePos()):
                self.selected_corner = point
                return

        if self.selectedItems():

            self.removeControlPoints()

            self.selected = self.selectedItems()[0]
            self.poly_points = [self.selected.mapToScene(x) for x in self.selected.polygon()]

            for index, point in enumerate(self.poly_points):
                x, y = point.x(), point.y()
                ellipse = self.addEllipse(QtCore.QRectF(x - 5, y - 5, 10, 10), brush=QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("red")))
                ellipse.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

                self.corner_points.append((ellipse, index))

        else:
            self.selected = None
            self.removeControlPoints()
            self.corner_points = []
            self.poly_points = []
            self.selected_corner = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event) -> None:
        super(Scene, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

        if self.selected_corner:
            self.poly_points[self.selected_corner[1]] = QtCore.QPointF(event.scenePos())
            self.selected.setPolygon(QtGui.QPolygonF(self.poly_points))

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event) -> None:
        super(Scene, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.selected_corner = None

    def addPoints(self):  # adds the polygon to the scene
        self.record_points = False
        polygon = self.addPolygon(QtGui.QPolygonF(self.points_lst))
        polygon.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.points_lst = []


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())

        view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
        scene = Scene()
        view.setScene(scene)

        record_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(text="Record", clicked=scene.record)
        finish_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(text="Finish", clicked=scene.addPoints)

        self.layout().addWidget(view)
        self.layout().addWidget(record_btn)
        self.layout().addWidget(finish_btn)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

output:

[image]